# index into Json properly using unity and c#

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

If I wanted to index into `price` or `galleryId` in this json file:

```
{
"searchId": null,
"listings": [{
    "sid": 0,
    "id": 25,
    "status": 3,
    "art": {
        "sid": 0,
        "artId": 24,
        "token": "v",
        "name": "A",
        "description": "F",
        "width": 18.0000,
        "height": 24.0000,
        "metricWidth": 0.4572,
        "metricHeight": 0.6096,
        "mediaType": "",
        "fullSizeImageUrl": "http",
        "thumbnailImageUrl": "http",
        "artist": {
            "token": null,
            "firstName": "V",
            "lastName": "G",
            "visibleInSearch": false,
            "inventoryVisibleInSearch": false
        }
    },
    "galleryId": 1,
    "price": 1750,
    "listed": "2020-01-18T21:49:41.447"
}]
```

would this be the correct syntax?

```
 {

        for (int i = 0; i < itemData[0]["listings"].Count; i++)

        {
         database.Add(new Art(itemData[0]["listings"][i]["galleryId"].ToString(), 
         (int)itemData[0]["listings"][i]["price"]));
```

Comment: Does it work? If not, what is the issue you're getting? (On a sidenote, it might be best to assign `var item = itemData[0]["listings"][i];` in your loop, then only use `item` in the consecutive line, for easier reading.)

Comment: the error i get is `KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.` which is the error consistent with not indexing into the json correctly

Comment: @PhilippLenssen for some reason it seems that I can use the loop to index into `galleryId` or `price`  - if I replace [i] for [1] i retrieve the data for that index of the json

Comment: The question is why I can i not use the loop?

Comment: Maybe some parts of this data (e.g. index 3) don't have a galleryId or price?

Answer (score 0):

@PhilippLenssen you were right, the json was incomplete and not all objects had the field galleryId - this is what broke my code. Thanks for making me look through the entire file!